# Angular lazyloading Home Component ngOninit & constructor called in every App navigation

Tags: angular

i have the following app route module config :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "moduleOne", loadChildren: () => import("./pages/moduleOne.module").then((module) => module.MyModuleOne)
      },
      {
        path: "moduleTwo", loadChildren: () => import("./pages/moduleOne.module").then((module) => module.MyModuleOne)
      },
      {
        path: "moduleThree", loadChildren: () => import("./pages/moduleThree.module").then((module) => module.MyModuleThree)
      }
    ],
  },

  { path: "error", component: ErrorComponent },
  { path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
  { path: "**", redirectTo: "error" },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: NoPreloading })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and this my home component:

```
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

          constructor() {
    
        console.log('... a new instance of HomeComponent has been created');
      }
    
    
      ngOnInit() {
          //service calls...
          console.log('ngOnInit HomeComponent Called');
    }
           
 }
```

in my application when i navigate on each route in different modules  , my HomeComponent is called  in each navigation and ngOninit & constructor executed and really i don't know why that's happen.
any one can suggest how to debug this issue.

Comment: are your using `RouterLink` or regular html anchors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing the ngOnInit and constructor of your HomeComponent being called on every navigation might be due to the fact that the HomeComponent is part of your root AppModule and not part of any lazy-loaded modules. This means that it's initialized once when the app starts and then re-initialized whenever there's a route change. Since your routes have the HomeComponent as a parent component for all routes, it gets re-initialized whenever any route changes.

If you want to prevent this behavior and have the HomeComponent only initialized once, you can consider moving it into a separate module that is not eagerly loaded by the app's root module. Then, when you navigate to routes that load modules, the HomeComponent won't be re-initialized with every route change.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  exports: [HomeComponent],
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    loadChildren: () => import("./home.module").then((module) => module.HomeModule),
    children: [
      {
        path: "moduleOne",
        loadChildren: () => import("./pages/moduleOne.module").then((module) => module.MyModuleOne),
      },
    ],
  },
];
```